# Android Navigation Drawer 遷移先をどう指定するか。

Tags: android, android-fragments

現在こちらのコードを参考にアプリを作っています。（初心者です。）
https://github.com/rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign

このDrawerMenuをクリックした時に、ListFragmentへ飛ばしたいのですが、何をどこに追記すればいいのでしょうか。
例えば、menuの0、inboxをクリックした時にListFragmentへ飛ばすなど。
お力添え頂けますと幸いです。

```
public class MainActivity extends NavigationLiveo implements NavigationLiveoListener {

    public List<String> mListNameItem;

    @Override
    public void onUserInformation() {
        //User information here
        this.mUserName.setText("Rudson Lima");
        this.mUserEmail.setText("rudsonlive@gmail.com");
        this.mUserPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_rudsonlive);
        this.mUserBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_user_background);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInt(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Creation of the list items is here

        // set listener {required}
        this.setNavigationListener(this);

        //First item of the position selected from the list
        this.setDefaultStartPositionNavigation(1);

        // name of the list items
        mListNameItem = new ArrayList<>();
        mListNameItem.add(0, getString(R.string.inbox));
        mListNameItem.add(1, getString(R.string.starred));
        mListNameItem.add(2, getString(R.string.sent_mail));
        mListNameItem.add(3, getString(R.string.drafts));
        mListNameItem.add(4, getString(R.string.more_markers)); //This item will be a subHeader
        mListNameItem.add(5, getString(R.string.trash));
        mListNameItem.add(6, getString(R.string.spam));

        // icons list items
        List<Integer> mListIconItem = new ArrayList<>();
        mListIconItem.add(0, R.drawable.ic_inbox_black_24dp);
        mListIconItem.add(1, R.drawable.ic_star_black_24dp); //Item no icon set 0
        mListIconItem.add(2, R.drawable.ic_send_black_24dp); //Item no icon set 0
        mListIconItem.add(3, R.drawable.ic_drafts_black_24dp);
        mListIconItem.add(4, 0); //When the item is a subHeader the value of the icon 0
        mListIconItem.add(5, R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp);
        mListIconItem.add(6, R.drawable.ic_report_black_24dp);

        //{optional} - Among the names there is some subheader, you must indicate it here
        List<Integer> mListHeaderItem = new ArrayList<>();
        mListHeaderItem.add(4);

        //{optional} - Among the names there is any item counter, you must indicate it (position) and the value here
        SparseIntArray mSparseCounterItem = new SparseIntArray(); //indicate all items that have a counter
        mSparseCounterItem.put(0, 7);
        mSparseCounterItem.put(1, 123);
        mSparseCounterItem.put(6, 250);

        //If not please use the FooterDrawer use the setFooterVisible(boolean visible) method with value false
        this.setFooterInformationDrawer(R.string.settings, R.drawable.ic_settings_black_24dp);

        this.setNavigationAdapter(mListNameItem, mListIconItem, mListHeaderItem, mSparseCounterItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClickNavigation(int position, int layoutContainerId) {

        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        Fragment mFragment = new FragmentMain().newInstance(mListNameItem.get(position));

        if (mFragment != null){
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(layoutContainerId, mFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenuNavigation(Menu menu, int position, boolean visible) {

        //hide the menu when the navigation is opens
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                menu.findItem(R.id.menu_add).setVisible(!visible);
                menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setVisible(!visible);
                break;

            case 1:
                menu.findItem(R.id.menu_add).setVisible(!visible);
                menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setVisible(!visible);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickUserPhotoNavigation(View v) {
        //user photo onClick
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.open_user_profile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickFooterItemNavigation(View v) {
        //footer onClick
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
    }




public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {

    private boolean mSearchCheck;
    private static final String TEXT_FRAGMENT = "TEXT_FRAGMENT";

    public FragmentMain newInstance(String text){
        FragmentMain mFragment = new FragmentMain();
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putString(TEXT_FRAGMENT, text);
        mFragment.setArguments(mBundle);
        return mFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        TextView mTxtTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        mTxtTitle.setText(getArguments().getString(TEXT_FRAGMENT));

        rootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));       
        return rootView;        
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        //Select search item
        final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        menuItem.setVisible(true);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint(this.getString(R.string.search));

        ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text))
            .setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.nliveo_white));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(onQuerySearchView);

        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_add).setVisible(true);

        mSearchCheck = false;   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_add:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.menu_search:
            mSearchCheck = true;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.search, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }   

   private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener onQuerySearchView = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
           if (mSearchCheck){
               // implement your search here
           }
           return false;
       }
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

以下で解決出来ました

```
@Override
    public void onItemClickNavigation(int position, int layoutContainerId) {

        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Fragment mFragment = new FragmentMain1);
                mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(layoutContainerId, mFragment).commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                Fragment mFragment2 = new FragmentMain2();
                mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(layoutContainerId, mFragment2).commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                Fragment mFragment3 = new FragmentMain3();
                mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(layoutContainerId, mFragment3).commit();
                break;
        }
    }
```